# Can't hear any audio on my Dell Inspiron 5559 after installing Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Tags: 14.04, drivers, sound, dell

The problem started when I deleted Win 10 and installed Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.

After a few weeks an update regression has caused my audio card to malfunction. I can't hear any sound and I do not know how to fix it.

I ran `lspci -v` and got this output:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d70 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 06b2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
    Memory at d1220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at d1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

Do you have any hints?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments but I need more information to be able to help you.  What type of Dell laptop are you running?  Some Dells have custom parameters that you need to pass to the snd_hda_intel module.

Second, please post the output of

```
aplay -l
```

I would start by reading this guide, which has helped me many times in the past: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto

Comment: I am using a Dell Inspiron 5559, Memory: 7.7 GiB, Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4, 64-bit

Here is the output of aplay -l:

******** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices **** card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0] Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1] Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2] Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0****

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Dell Inspiron 5559, Memory: 7.7 GiB, Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4, 64-bit

Here is the output of `aplay -l`:

******** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

```
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0****
```

Thank you.

P.S. I read on some forums that people have had this issue and they upgraded their kernel from 3.16.xxx to 4.2.xxxx. My Ubuntu distribution came with the 4.2.xxx and the issue is persisting.

Answer (score 0):

as I mentioned before, you can try various mod options.  try this http://docs.slackware.com/howtos:hardware:audio_and_snd-hda-intel

Comment: None of the mod options I tried work. Not even the guide that you provided earlier.

Comment: finally I can comment...  try a kernel upgrade.  

    $ sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-wily

the xenial kernel is there too.  I'm currently running 14.04.4 with the xenial kernel to have my skylake GPU work

Comment: My kernel version is: **4.2.0-35-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 16:37:35 UTC 2016 x86_64** I also can't see the audio controller in BIOS

Comment: yeah 4.2 is older than the xenial kernel, which is 4.4